# How to extract a list of tuple from a list with each element paired with exactly one other element?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I am new to Haskell and I got a question. How can I write a function that takes an even length list of values and returns a list of tuples? Each element in the list should be paired with exactly one other element.

For example : [1, 2, 3, 4] would give [(1,2),(3,4)] or [(1,3),(2,4)]or[(1,4),(2,3)]

Comment: *[(1,2),(3,4)] or [(1,3),(2,4)]* what do you mean by "or" exactly? Is this "I don't care which of the results is returned", or "it should return one of the results depending on some condition", oor "it should return all of the results", or something else?

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow is not a service where people will just write code for you. You have to show your attemts or any effort that you applied to solve the task and demonstrate us problems that you've encountered on that way.

If you just ask people to solve your task, they'll get angry at you (-3 score of this question states exactly that), and your question will be closed. So make sure you demonstrate enough effort in solving a task when asking about it here.

BTW, I'll give you a hint:

```
pairUp :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
pairUp [] = [] -- obvious case
pairUp [x] = error "Odd-length list!"
pairUp (x:y:xs) = ...
```

You have to complete the last case. Here you have first two elements `x` and `y`, and also the tail list of all other elements. You have to combine the first two elements in a pair and also process the tail in the same way. You will need an understanding [recursion](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion#hello-recursion) to accomplish the task.

Comment: Downvoting isn't about getting angry. Downvoting helps remove the dross from the valuable.